How to swap colors between two buttons in wordpress with elementor
In wordpress using elementor I added two buttons that display different content. When the button1 is clicked it shows the price_list1 and hide the price_list2. When the button2 is clicked the price_list2 is visible and the price_list1 is hidden. The problem is that both buttons have the same color and is not clear which price list is active.
I need to setup different colors for the active button (the clicked one) and non-active one.
How can I do this?
No expirience with JS and CSS but understanding the structure and commands
